# Unable to send emails while i pass headers to mail() function

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send emails with HTML content and whenever i pass headers of any kind the method `mail()` return false but with no headers i get true .. any clue ?

```
                $to         = $user->email;
                $name       = $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;
                $from       = $this->config->item('admin_email', 'ion_auth');
                $subject    = $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('email_forgotten_password_subject');

                $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From:  ' . $name . ' <' . $from .'>' . " \r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.  $from . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

                die(var_dump($retval));
```

Comment: I don't see where you're passing headers in mail

Comment: You're not passing any headers at all in that code. Did you mean to pass `$headers` as a variable?

Comment: Nor do we know where those other variables are.

Comment: Oh sorry i removed for testing and forgot to return it when i made the question .. but still even if headers passed i get false

Comment: I'm not usually a big fan of suggesting to use a different method altogether in response to a question, but for PHP's `mail()` function I make an exception. There are much less painful ways to do it. Try PHPMailer or Swift mailer.

Comment: False means you may have syntax errors. Check for them

Comment: @Ben does PHPMailer  or Swift mailer work in shared hosting i think this is for SMTP emails right ?

Comment: @YasserMoussa. I've used PHPMailer in the past, and it's just possible to drop the entire code in as a library if your hosting is gonna be difficult. Yes! It uses SMTP.

Comment: Are you sure the mail() fonction is available in your configuration cf php.ini ? Do you have any logs ?

Comment: I agree -- quit making things difficult for yourself. Throw away your code and download phpMailer instead. It can send via the `mail()` function if you want it to (but takes away all the complexity) or it can also send via SMTP. I honestly don't understand why anyone bothers trying to hack around with the `mail()` function when libs like phpMailer exist.

Comment: @Simba i didn't know i can use phpmailer since my host seems not to allow codeigniter SMTP email library to work and the only one start sending emails is mail() .. ok i installed phpmailer but how can i get it to send using mail() not SMTP ??

Comment: phpMailer defaults to using `mail()` function; it only switches to SMTP if you specify it, and also specify the SMTP credentials. But also, what kind of crazy host are you using that doesn't allow you to use a third-party SMTP? That's a totally standard thing to do (and almost always better than php `mail()` for several important technical reasons). Heck, I've worked with hosts that don't allow local mail and insist that you use SMTP.

Comment: @Simba i am using godaddy shared hosting :-/ i tried codeigniter's default email library which uses SMTP but didn't work and the only thing worked for me so far mail() .. even i tried phpmailer and still got this :-(

bool(false) 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Having read that, my opinion of GoDaddy has gone down even more (and I didn't think much of them to start with). Have you considered finding a better web host? But if `mail()` function works, you should be able to get phpMailer working though it as well; Try following this example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that variables `$name`, `$from`, `$to`, `$subject` has the right data and are not empty/null. Your code is functional and should send the email.

If still doesn't work, check the configurations on postfix or what other mail server you're using.

And I suggest to use PhpMailer or SwiftMailer instead of simple mail function.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `CRLF` after your last header. Used to work for me in the olden days.

i.e.,

```
...
$headers .= 'From:  ' . $name . ' <' . $from .'>' . " \r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.  $from . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
...
```

Also, the header `Content-Type` has a capital `T`. Sometimes, such trivial things may also break it. That's why everyone suggests to move away from it.

That should do it.

Suggestion: Switch to [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).